# Exchange 2010 update timezone of all calendar items

Tags: exchange-2010, timezone

We are currently operating Exchange 2010 server with Outlook 2010 clients on a ship. We have just changed timezones for the first time in quite a while today. Is there any way to rebase all the calendars and/or update all the calendar items to the new timezone at the same time?

I have looked at the following tools already.

- Microsoft Exchange Calendar Update Configuration Tool - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6266 (Doesn't support exchange 2010)
- Time Zone Data Update Tool for Microsoft Office Outlook - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17291

The Time Zone Data Update Tool for Microsoft Office Outlook does work for individual users, but has some serious downsides. Including each user needs to run it (approx 400 users), and also it only seems to work on the default account in Outlook 2010, a lot of our users have role accounts as well that we would need to run the tool on. The only way I can find to get this tool to run on the role accounts is to make the role account the default account in outlook, and that in itself is quiet an involved process especially if you have 2 or 3 role accounts.

So is there a way to just change all calendar items on our Exchange server to a different timezone in one go? We are a little unique in terms of the whole organisation can change timezones over night, meeting rooms and all, but surely a product as advanced as Exchange 2010 allows us to do what we need.

Comment: "the whole organisation can change timezones over night"  as in like, the whole company hops on a plane and leaves the country?  Sounds like a fly by night operation to me.

Comment: Well, he *SAID* they're on a ship...

Comment: Yes massimo thats right, we are on a ship. The exchange servers, outlook 2010 clients everything, all on the ship.

Answer (score 1):

I also have a client that has offices on shore, and a ship (with Exchange at both locations)... they just operate on CST time on-board, and just make the necessary adjustments with scheduling with on-shore people when they happen to be in the EST timezone.

An alternative might be to some-how adjust the timezone on everyone's computers... Outlook should recognize that the PC's timezone is now X and show the calendars and received time based on the 'local' timezone. The exchange server (and everything else) can remain on the original timezone (or set all the servers to UTC).

Comment: Thanks for response Doug, the ship doesn't move around that much, so it makes sense to set the timezone to the country we are docked in. We adjusted all the timezones of the computers via group policy already. The problem is that all the appointments were created in the old timezone and outlook 2010 is clever enough to factor that in so all the appointments are now an hour out, thats why im looking for a way to rebase all the appointments at the same time. (Timezone change was to UTC+1 from UTC)